# Five cards are dealt off a standard 52-card deck problem

Tags: combinatorics

Is this approach to the given problems correct?

---

Five cards are dealt off a standard 52-card deck. How many line-ups are there in which all 5 cards are of the same suit?

My approach:

There are four suits and thirteen card values, so we have four types of lists. Each type of list can produce $13*12*11*10*9$ lists. So there are $4*(13*12*11*10*9)=617,760$ possible line-ups in which all 5 cards are of the same suit.

---

Five cards are dealt off a standard 52-card deck. How many such line-ups are there in which exactly one of the 5 cards is a queen?

My approach:

We have five types of lists. For each type of list in which there is exactly one queen produces $51*50*49*48$ different lists. So there are $5*(51*50*49*48)=29,988,000$ possible line-ups in which exactly one of the 5 cards is a queen.

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: This is assuming the order is important (normally with hands dealt, we do not care about the order of the cards). If we disregard order we have to divide by $5!$. For the queen question, pick one out of 4 queens and 4 cards from the remainig no-queens (48). Divide by $5!$ for disregarding order.

Comment: Remember that the order of cards in a hand does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming line up means you only care about the first $5$ cards the solution to the first problem is correct. For the solution of the second you forgot to take away the queens and you also forgot to pick which of the four queens it is that you have.

If the order does not matter you need to divide by $5!$

Under are hidden solutions if the order does not matter:

> Solution to the first problem: First select the suit in $4$ ways and then there are $\binom{13}{5}$ ways to choose $5$ from the $13$ of that suit. Final solution is $4\binom{13}{5}$

---

> Solution to the second problem: First select which of the queens you want in $4$ ways. After that you must choose $4$ cards out of the $48$ non-queen cards, this can be done in $\binom{48}{4}$ ways. Hence the answer is $4\binom{48}{4}$

Comment: Can you elaborate? I considered starting with 48 × 47 × 46 × 45 for each list. But the problem specifies for exactly one queen selected.

Comment: exactly, so the other cards can't have a queen among them.

Comment: Oh yeah. I see. So would 5 times 48×47×46×45 be correct?

Comment: if the order matters it would be $5\times 48\times 47\times 46\times 45$ multiplied by $4$ since you haven't said which of the queens you want, only the position in which the queen is

Comment: Hmm, but i'm still confused. I'm not sure if the question is ambiguous or i'm still misunderstanding it. Consider this line: "exactly one of the 5 cards is a queen" what prevents me from having 2,3,4 queens in a line? as it does not say "exactly only one of the 5 cards is a queen"?

Comment: When they say there is exactly one queen they mean the quantity of queens is $1$. Otherwise they wouldn't have said the word exactly.

Comment: Ok, understood. I have to get used to this I guess. Thanks for your help!